# How should I take a series of input in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I used the below given function inpvec but it didn't work because when i used the function in the main function there was no output using the iterators...

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;

 void inpvec(vector <int> a, int veclen){
     int b;
     for(int i=0;i<veclen;i++){
         cin>>b;
         a.push_back(b);
     }
 }

 int main()
 {
     int n,j;
     cin >>n;
     vector <int> vac;
     vector <int> pat;
     vector <int>::iterator it;
     inpvec(vac, n);
     inpvec(pat, n);
     for(it=vac.begin();it!=vac.end();it++){
         cout<<*it<<" ";
     }
     for(it=pat.begin();it!=pat.end();it++){
         cout<<*it<<" ";
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You should consider spending some good time studying the nature of C++ types and memory: pointers/references vs plain variables. Try to understand the difference between `int b = 1; int a = b; a = 2;` and `int a = 1; int* b = &a; b = 2;`. Check this [link](http://cpp.sh/8zj4v)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function

```
void inpvec(vector <int> a, int veclen)
```

makes a copy of the first parameter `a`. so the calling code will see no difference.

Making it a reference will change that

```
void inpvec(vector <int> & a, int veclen)
//                       ^----- this
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a copy of the vector here:

```
void inpvec(vector <int> a, int veclen)
```

You need to pass it by reference:

```
void inpvec(vector <int>& a, int veclen)
________________________^_______________
```